Spring standalone DoIT program
I need to write some custom business logic that it requires to be executed before the application is deployed.
This custom business logic should re-use the existing business services together with JPA repository.
I don't want to use Spring Hook to execute this logic. I want to create a standalone main program which can be triggered from command line. The reason why is not fine for me a Spring Hook because we want to be able to implement and run this kind of custom service during application is deployed as well.
Is there any library which I can reuse so I don't need to implement: how we are calling the main program to be executed together with the SpringContext/DB Connect to be created for this main program?

so you need to execute business logic using services inside of an application BUT you need to execute it BEFORE the application starts? The way you describe it this is a Chicken and Egg problem. I would say you should reconsider your design by extracting the logic that you need in both BEFORE and DURING into a separate library and then reuse that llibrary in another app that does the BEFORE logic. If it should be started from commandline and doesn't need server (http) you could use Spring Shell.

The spring-shell is a code recommendation. I tried out and it will solve this issue. Thanks.
